# make a factory of factory

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have two factory:

```
class Factory
{
   public static function getInstance($type) {
     .....
   }
}
```

and

```
class Factory
{
   public static function getInstance($type) {
     .....
   }

}
```

so, now I want to make an factory of my two factory like this :

```
class FactoryOfFactory
{
  public static function getFactory($service)
  {
    switch ($service) {
      case 'fac1':
        $Factory = new Factory();
        break;
      case 'fac2':
        $Factory = new Factory();
    }

    return $Factory
  }
}
```

so I don't know to differentiate my two factory

thank for help

Comment: Give them different names?

Comment: Put them in a namespace

Answer (score 0):

For a start, your Singleton design should be a trait, not repeated through-out the classes.

```
trait Singleton
{
    private ?object $_instance;

    protected function __construct() {}
    private   function __clone    () {}

    public static function GetInstance() {
        if(($i &= self::$_instance)) return $i;
        $i = new self();
        return $i;
    }
}
```

Secondly, you cannot require two classes that are within the same namespace. You must declare separate namespaces.

```
namespace App;

class Factory {
    use Singleton;
}

namespace App\Custom;

class Factory {
    use Singleton;
}
```

From here, you can now use them like so:

```
namespace App;

use App\Custom\Factory as FactoryTwo;

class FactoryOfFactory {
    use Singleton;

    protected function __construct() {
        FactoryTwo::GetInstance();
        Factory::GetInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use meaningful names.
Factories are generally used (and misused) to initialize complex objects, hiding the creational complexity. They're different from the Builder pattern because a Factory might execute calls to external services before returning a result.

In your example, you should rename the factories based on the domain object they're trying to build. Eg: CustomerRepositoryFactory, OrderFactory and so on.

But before you do that, let me ask you this: why in the world would you need a Factory of a Factory? From your usage of the `static` keyword, I suppose you're not making use of Dependency Injection. Try to refactor your code in that direction instead.